# How to find the original position of a point knowing its position after rotation?

Tags: geometry

Given a square, I want to get the original coordinates of the top left vertex after a rotation is performed on the square, knowing the new coordinates of the top left vertex and the angle of rotation.

For example, how could I find point P

[image: in this figure]

knowing the square has been rotated 18.4 degrees and that the new coordinates P' are (0.35, 0.18)?

Edit: The centre of rotation is the centre of the square (e.g. `C (0.5, 0.4)`)

Comment: What is the centre of rotation?

Comment: Forgot to mention that, the center of the location it's the centre of the square. For example: C (0.5, 0.4)

Comment: Your posting is missing several details.
Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: If the centre of rotation is instead the origin, do you know how to rotate any point by $18.4^\circ$?

Comment: Rotate it by the negative of the angle.

Comment: inverse of your rotation matrix will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot solve without knowing where the center of rotation is. If you know the coordinates $(a,b)$ of the center of the rectangle, and if the rotated point is at $(r_x,r_y)$, with angle $\theta$ then

$$ x = a + (r_x-a) \cos \theta - (r_y-b) \sin \theta $$
$$ y = b + (r_x-a) \sin \theta + (r_y-b) \cos \theta $$

<sub>Note: But, given the coordinate system definition, I might have the sense of a positive rotation flipped.</sub>

Comment: How would the equations of x and y change given my coordinate system?

Comment: @JaviAlbors - You have _y_ down, and angles are clockwise. This is how I have the equations above setup. They consist of moving the origin to the center of rotation, doing the inverse rotation, and then moving back to the origin.